# Numpy 3d array - normalize rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I've been working on normalizing image data with horizontal dark/bright lines.

Please find my minimal working example below.
Let there be a 3d array (three images):

```
import numpy as np
a= np.arange(3)#
a= np.vstack([a,a+3,a+6])
a= np.repeat(a,3,axis=0)#.reshape((3,3,3))
a = a.reshape(3,3,3)
```

For instance, image #2  `a[:,:,1]` consists of

```
[[1 1 1]
 [4 4 4]
 [7 7 7]]
```

[image: visual representation of Image #2]

and shows horizontal streaks. To get rid of the streaks I am calculating the median of the rows, the overall median and a difference matrix.

```
row_median = np.median(a, axis=1)
bg_median= np.tile(np.median(a, axis=[0,1]),(3,1))
difference_matrix= bg_median-row_median
```

Subsequently, I am iterating through the images and apply the difference matrix to all images.

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[:,:,i] = a[:,:,i] + np.tile(difference_matrix[:,i],(3,1)).T
```

This gives the desired result, e.g., in  `a[:,:,1]` :

```
[[4 4 4]
 [4 4 4]
 [4 4 4]]
```

This procedure is very slow for large images and stacks of images.
I would appreciate any comments and hints for improving the performance of my code, possible through the use of **broadcasting**.

**EDIT:**
Following up on [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62662134/5818240)

```
a = a.astype('float64')
diff = np.median(a, axis=[0,1]) - np.median(a, axis=0))
a += diff[None,:]
```

solved the issue for me.

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Leverage [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) upon extending dimensions with `None/np.newaxis` instead of tiling those intermediate arrays, to save on memory and hence to achieve perf. effciency. Hence, the changes would be -

```
diff = np.median(a, axis=[0,1]) - np.median(a, axis=1)
a += diff[:,None]
```

This takes care of the dimensionality extension under the hoods.

**Approach #2**

Alternatively, a more explicit way to keep track of dims, would be to keep them while performing data reductio and thus avoid the final dim extension with `None`. So, we can use `keepdims` as `True` with them -

```
diff = np.median(a,axis=(0,1),keepdims=True) - np.median(a, axis=1,keepdims=True)
a += diff
```